# How to create a time delay between two animations in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, doubleanimation

I am new in WPF, I just want to animate **two objects one after the other**. That means that 2nd animation should start after 1st is finished. I tried using Timer and Sleep methods which didn't work well. Below is a sample code:

```
DoubleAnimation da1 = new DoubleAnimation()
{

   From = 10,
   To = 200,
   Duration = new System.Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec)),
};


temLabel1.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, da1);
Delay(); // Delay when busy

DoubleAnimation da2 = new DoubleAnimation()
{

   From = 300,
   To = 500,
   Duration = new System.Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec)),
};

ItemLabels2.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, da2);
```

I am using `Timer` to create a time delay between two animations

```
 /* Setting Timer For delay during animation */

  timer.Interval = sec * 1000 + 50;
  timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
```

The code for delay function is :

```
void Delay()
{
     busy = true;
     timer.Start();

     while (busy) {}
}
```

Timer Elapsed Event Handler

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    busy = false;
    timer.Stop();
 }
```

Please correct me where I am wrong. I don't want to use Note: `DoubleAnimation.Completed` event handler for this purpose because It will be difficult when dealing with and animating a collection of objects through loop.
Your Response will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
private int sec = 2;

private async Task StartAnimation()
{
    await StartAnimationForLabel1();
    await StartAnimationForLabel2();
}

private async Task StartAnimationForLabel1()
{
    DoubleAnimation da1 = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        From = 10,
        To = 200,
        Duration = new System.Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec)),
    };
     ItemLabel1.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, da1);
    await Task.Delay(sec * 1000); 
}

private async Task StartAnimationForLabel2()
{
    DoubleAnimation da2 = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        From = 300,
        To = 500,
        Duration = new System.Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec)),

    };
    ItemLabels2.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, da2);
    await Task.Delay(sec * 1000);
}
```

to know more about Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await see [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx)

> Require .NET Framework 4.5 or more

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 options

1. Use [Completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed(v=vs.110).aspx) event on Animation - in event handler start the second animation
2. Use [Storyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx) to chain the animations

I think option 1 suits your needs.